# ExtJS grid won't refresh after setHeight

Tags: javascript, extjs, height, refresh

I made a GridPanel by ExtJS 3.4, height:200. I need to change the height sometimes.

When I setHeight(65) to make it shorter, and then setHeight back to its original height: 200, the grid seems returned to be 200 height with border, but the contents inside remains the look as I set it to the height of 65.
I have tried below after setHeight, but no luck:

```
     grid.setHeight(200);
    //myStore.load();
    //myStore.reload();
    //myStore.getStore().load();
    //grid.render();
    //grid.getView().refresh();
    //grid.getView().refresh(true);
    //grid.getView().updateLayout();
    //grid.doLayout();  //just tried not okay
```

[image: the grid won't refresh]

```js
//the code:
   grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
        id: "myGrid",
        store: myStore,
        selModel: mySelectionModel,
        columns: [
            mySelectionModel,
            {
                id: 'name',
                header: "Item",
                width: 240,
                menuDisabled: true,
                dataIndex: 'name'
            }
        ],
        height: 200,
        width: 280,
        listeners: {
            "keydown": function (e) {
                if (e.getKey() == 17) {
                    mySelectionModel.clearSelections();
                }
            }
        }
    });
//another item on top of the gird enlarged code here, so shorter the grid:
grid.setHeight(65)
//the item on top returned to be smaller code here
//so then I return the height of the grid to its original in the line below:
grid.setHeight(200);
//however, after the above line, the content remains as the height of 65
```

Comment: can you please add a simple fiddle?

Comment: Or simply add more code? what is grid? the grid or the grid view?

Answer (score 0):

Strange. I've tried to simplify the code and the grid content height is correctly set even after changing height. What layout is your parent container using?

Example (https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1l7c):

```
Ext.onReady(function() {    
  var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({    
    title: 'People',    
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),    
    store: new Ext.data.JsonStore({    
      fields: [ 'id', 'name' ],    
      data: [    
        { id: 1, name: 'Jack' },    
        { id: 2, name: 'Brian' },    
        { id: 3, name: 'John' },    
        { id: 4, name: 'James' },    
        { id: 5, name: 'Anna' },    
        { id: 6, name: 'Dorothy' },    
        { id: 7, name: 'Mike' },    
        { id: 8, name: 'Daisy' },    
        { id: 9, name: 'Brian' },    
        { id: 10, name: 'Brian' }    
      ]    
    }),    
    columns: [    
      { header: "Id", width: 50, menuDisabled: true, dataIndex: 'id' },    
      { header: "Name", width: 150, menuDisabled: true, dataIndex: 'name' }    
    ],    
    height: 200,    
    width: 280    
  });    

  grid.setHeight(60);    
  grid.setHeight(200);    
  grid.setHeight(90);    
  grid.setHeight(150);    
});
```

Comment: just tried, if set height and short together it did return the same table, but in my code, I have function to enlarge all items and another function to shorter all items. And the grid is inside a Ext.panel, not sure are they the reason, let me try simplify my code and provide more fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out how to do! Thanks for all your effort. Sorry as the codes are too much, so I didn't say it in detail at the very beginning.
the gird is inside the 3rd tab of Ext.TabPanel, and in fact when I want to restore all items to its normal, the view will return to the 1st tab.
all I need to do is below:

```
myContainer = new Ext.TabPanel({
//other properties of TabPanel
   listeners: {
     "tabchange": function (tabpanel, tab) {
     if (tab.tabid == 3) { //the tab where the grid are
       grid.getView().refresh();
     }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this after setting new Width
**grid.doLayout();**

```
Try the below fiddle
```

[jsfiddle.net/praveensov/7kpZ9/737](http://jsfiddle.net/praveensov/7kpZ9/737) 
this is updated fiddle with setting height

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/praveensov/7kpZ9/737/ this is updated fiddle with setting height